# lxd init gives dnsmasq error -- address already in use

Tags: networking, dnsmasq, lxd

When trying out lxd on a desktop ubuntu 18.04, I get the following error

```
 sudo lxd init                         
Would you like to use LXD clustering? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Do you want to configure a new storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
Name of the new storage pool [default=default]: 
Name of the storage backend to use (btrfs, ceph, dir, lvm, zfs) [default=zfs]: dir
Would you like to connect to a MAAS server? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like to create a new local network bridge? (yes/no) [default=yes]: 
What should the new bridge be called? [default=lxdbr0]: 
What IPv4 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]: 
What IPv6 address should be used? (CIDR subnet notation, “auto” or “none”) [default=auto]: none
Would you like LXD to be available over the network? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Would you like stale cached images to be updated automatically? (yes/no) [default=yes] 
Would you like a YAML "lxd init" preseed to be printed? (yes/no) [default=no]: 
Error: Failed to create network 'lxdbr0': Failed to run: dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.pid --except-interface=lo --no-ping --interface=lxdbr0 --quiet-dhcp --quiet-dhcp6 --quiet-ra --listen-address=10.139.93.1 --dhcp-no-override --dhcp-authoritative --dhcp-leasefile=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.leases --dhcp-hostsfile=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.hosts --dhcp-range 10.139.93.2,10.139.93.254,1h -s lxd -S /lxd/ --conf-file=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.raw -u lxd: Failed to run: dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.pid --except-interface=lo --no-ping --interface=lxdbr0 --quiet-dhcp --quiet-dhcp6 --quiet-ra --listen-address=10.139.93.1 --dhcp-no-override --dhcp-authoritative --dhcp-leasefile=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.leases --dhcp-hostsfile=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.hosts --dhcp-range 10.139.93.2,10.139.93.254,1h -s lxd -S /lxd/ --conf-file=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/networks/lxdbr0/dnsmasq.raw -u lxd: dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 10.139.93.1: Address already in use
```

I've checked and before I ran  the command, i could verify that dnsmasq is not listening on 10.139.93.1. After running the above command, it is running on 10.139.93.1, so the error does hold merrit, but seems self-inflicted.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might seems self-inflicted, lxd actually wants to run another dnsmasq process, whereas the dnsmasq instance you see after running the command is most probably the system/existing dnsmasq instance being very quick to start a socket on the newly created lxd bridge; the lxd bridge being created by the `lxd init` command

libvirt has the same problem, but actually solves this (on ubuntu) by having a file in `/etc/dnsmasq.d/libvirt-daemon` having the crucial line starting with `except-interface=...`

The same is needed for lxd, I believe it would start to work if you add the following line to `/etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd`:

```
except-interface=lxdbr0
```